# create new user in quickblox (javascript)

Tags: quickblox

I was trying to use quickbox javascript api for chat application in my website. I used quickblox  example and  it's working good.But i didn't understand how to create new user. Any one have any code or tuorials or links on this share it.

Answer (score 5):

Use this example code for creating users:

```
var params = {login: 'quickblox', password: 'quickblox334'};
QB.users.create(params, function(err, user) {
  // callback function

  if (user) {
    // user - JS obejct with QB user 
  }

});
```

You can use any parameters from QB USERS API in params variable.
http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#User_Sign_Up

Comment: But I got the token missing error -- Object {code: 401, status: "error", message: "Unauthorized", detail: "{"errors":["Token is required"]}"}, any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I found the reason. Because I don't create a session before creating user. Although the code of creating session is ahead of the one of creating user. But it's asychorized.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use email behave of login :-

```
var params = {email: 'quickblox@gmail.com', password: 'quickblox334'};
QB.users.create(params, function(err, user) {
   // callback function
  if (user) {
    // user - JS obejct with QB user 
  }
});
```

But you need to create session first to create a user. If you not create a session for quickblox then you get **Token is required error**.

You can **create session** using this POC :

First initialize QB using this line :

```
 QB.init(CREDENTIALS.appId, CREDENTIALS.authKey, CREDENTIALS.authSecret);
```

Then create session :

```
 QB.createSession(function(err, result) {
    // callback function
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var QB = require('quickblox');

    // our parameters to connect to QuickBlox Chat service
    var CHAT = {
      server: 'chat.quickblox.com'
    };

    var CREDENTIALS = {
      appId: 55,
      authKey: 'ABCDE45415212',
      authSecret: 'ddf5456ffgf'
    };

    QB.init(CREDENTIALS.appId, CREDENTIALS.authKey, CREDENTIALS.authSecret);


    var params = { 'login': QuickBloxlogin(via email or username), 'pass': QuickBloxlogin Password};



    var user1 = { 'login': "new_user, 'password': "new_user_password"};


    QB.createSession(params, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.detail);
      } else {
        console.log(res);

        QB.users.create(user1, function(err, user) {
           // callback function
          if (err) {
              console.log(err.detail);
          }else {
              // user - JS obejct with QB user
                console.log('Users created');
          }
        });

// Link for more functions of users https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-users-javascript#Update_your_own_profile


//This function will update the user based on his id


QB.users.update(user_id, {full_name: "My Name", email: "My emailid"}, function(err, user){
  if (user) {
     // success
  } else  {
     // error
  }
});

//This function will list out all the users with total records 100 in a single page
    var user_params = { page: '1', per_page: '100'};

    QB.users.listUsers(user_params, function(err, users_list){
      if (err) {
        // error
      } else {
        // success
        console.log(users_list);
      }
    });



 //This function will delete the user based on his id
       QB.users.delete(user_id, function(err, user){
       if (user) {
        // success
      } else  {
        // error
      }
    });
   }
  });
```

Firstly import the quickblox package

Then get your credentials like appID, authKey, authSecret by registering your account in quickblox https://admin.quickblox.com

After this, enter your quickblox credentials for creating the session.

Now you can create the new user when you follow al the above steps

QuickBlox Docs for JavaScript:- https://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript

For more functions relating to user you can fing the same by visition quickblox site 
https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-users-javascript#Update_your_own_profile

Sometimes you need to retrieve all your QuickBlox users. But there is one restriction: you can retrieve a maximum of 100 users per query.

Here is an example how to retrieve all users:

```
var usersCount = 0;

function retrieveAllUsersFromPage(page_number) {
  var params = { page: page_number, per_page: '100'};
  QB.users.listUsers(params, function(err, result){
    if (result) {
      usersCount += result.items.length;
      if(result.total_entries > usersCount){
        retrieveAllUsersFromPage(result.per_page+1);
      }
    } else {
      // error
    }
  });
}

// Start
retrieveAllUsersFromPage(1);
```

It's possible to use some filters and sort parameters:

```
var params = {filter: { field: 'email', param: 'eq', value: 'nobody@nowhere.org' }};

QB.users.listUsers(params, function(err, result){
  if (result) {
    // success
  } else {
    // error
  }
});
```

// Retrieve Users with IDs

```
var params = {filter: { field: 'id', param: 'in', value: [2,3] }};

QB.users.listUsers(params, function(err, result){
  if (result) {
    // success
  } else  {
    // error
  }
});
```

// Retrieve Users with tags

```
var params = {tags: ["man", "golf"]};

QB.users.get(params, function(err, result){
  if (result) {
    // success
  } else  {
    // error
  }
});
```

// Retrieve Users with full names

```
var params = {full_name: ["Graay Sabs", "Samuel Camy"]};

QB.users.get(params, function(err, result){
  if (result) {
    // success
  } else  {
    // error
  }
});
```

// Retrieve User by id

```
QB.users.get(72, function(err, result){
  if (result) {
    // success
  } else  {
    // error
  }
});
```

// Retrieve User with Facebook ID

```
var params = {facebook_id: "11227884521232"};


    QB.users.get(params, function(err, result){
      if (result) {
        // success
      } else  {
        // error
      }
    });
```

// Retrieve User with Twitter ID

```
var params = {twitter_id: "27884521232"};

QB.users.get(params, function(err, result){
  if (result) {
    // success
  } else  {
    // error
  }
});
```

//Retrieve User with an external ID

```
var params = {external: "884521232"};

QB.users.get(params, function(err, result){
  if (result) {
    // success
  } else  {
    // error
  }
});
```

Happy Coding :)